# Get high resolution contact photo

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know how to retrieve the high quality photo of a telephonebook contact (user)?
All of my tries resulted in low quality images...

It doesn't matter If I retrieve it via "openContactPhotoInputStream" or via an "Uri", both are in low quality. It looks like Thumbnails.

My approaches:

## 1

```
private void retrieveContactPhoto(ImageView imgView, Long contactId) {

    Bitmap photo = null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts
                .openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                                contactId));

        if (inputStream != null) {
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

        assert inputStream != null;
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

## 2

```
public static Uri getPhotoUri(long contactId) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = MainActivity.instance
            .getContentResolver();

    try {
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver
                .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                + "="
                                + contactId
                                + " AND "

                                + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                + "='"
                                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                                + "'", null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return null; // no photo
            }
        } else {
            return null; // error in cursor process
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(person,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
}
```

Min SDK is set to android version 4.3.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the other overloaded method of `openContactPhotoInputStream` (added in API level 14), the one with the boolean parameter indicating that you prefer high res photos.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#openContactPhotoInputStream(android.content.ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#openContactPhotoInputStream%28android.content.ContentResolver), android.net.Uri, boolean)

```
public static InputStream openContactPhotoInputStream
        (ContentResolver cr, Uri contactUri, boolean preferHighres)
```

Comment: On a side note.. new to Chrome, does anyone how to copy-paste a link formatted URL from my URL bar? My above link has spaces in it, can't figure it out on Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Quite simple... The new overload method works like a charm. Thank you very much ;).

Comment: Still shows low quality for me, (LG G3) seems to depend more on whether the contact service had actually sync'd the full size image or not, and it only seems to do that if I open up the contact image in the contacts up

Comment: @behelit Did you solve this somehow? I see the same behavior...